# What changes make fishing more interesting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The [1.7.2 Minecraft update](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/post/65040832258/minecraft-1-7-2) says that fishing has been changed.

> Fishing is now more interesting

What's more interesting about it? What has changed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from the [changelog for 1.7.2 on the minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#1.7.2)

Fishing

- Changes to fishing mechanics
- Items other than fish can be obtained by fishing.

  - Fish: 4 items total, including Raw Fish, Raw Salmon, Clownfish, and Pufferfish.
  - Treasure: 7 items total, including enchanted fishing rods, enchanted bow, enchanted books, name tags, tripwire hook, lilypads, and saddles.
  - Junk: 11 items total, including damaged fishing rods, water bottles, rotten flesh, string, leather, bowls, sticks, boots or damaged boots.
- New enchantments for Fishing Rods that can change your luck when fishing.

  - Lure - reduces wait time to catch an item.
  - Luck of the Sea - increases chance of getting treasure and decreases chance of getting junk.